# Error compiling simple c++ hello world for Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm using Archlinux and I have a simple C++ file `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to compile it to run on *Android*.

I download *Android NDK* zip file, I extract it, and I follow the instructions on the official website https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#non-autoconf_make_projects

I run:

```
export NDK=/home/myuser/dnsmasq-Android/android-ndk-r26b/
export ANDROID_NDK=$NDK
export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$NDK
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH

export TARGET=armv7a-linux-androideabi
export API=34
```

The path `$TOOLCHAIN/bin` now gives me access to the compiler executable `armv7a-linux-androideabi34-clang++`.

But if I run `armv7a-linux-androideabi34-clang++ main.cpp`, I get the error:

```
clang-17: error: no input files
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I tried another way: Inside the `./android-ndk-r26b` extracted folder, I create a `jni` folder. Inside it I put 3 files: The `main.cpp` above, `Application.mk` containing:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
# x86 # mips
APP_PLATFORM := android-33
#APP_STL := stlport_static
```

And `Android.mk` containing:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
#CFLAGS += -fvisibility=default -fPIE
#LDFLAGS += -rdynamic -fPIE -pie
# give module name
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello_world  
# list your C files to compile
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
# this option will build executables instead of building library for android application.
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Now inside `./android-ndk-r26b/jni` I run the command:

```
../ndk-build
```

The terminal hangs and nothing happened. I tried leaving it for an hour but nothing changed. It seems like it is stuck..

I can't solve this either..